# Can I create an AIR app which will only run with the provided CD?

Tags: air, cd-rom

I'm looking to make an AIR application.  However, unlike the normal distro, I want to sell these on a CD.  I want the AIR app to only be able to be run when the CD is in the CD drive (I don't care that people can hack around this, its the default behavior I want)  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get drive list with:

```
var drives:Array = File.getRootDirectories();
```

Next, you want to check ones with spaceAvailable = 0 if they contain files like on your CD. If the disk isn't in the drive, drive will not be listed in array.